# bootstrap3 nav close when clicking with dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i use bs3 and my mobile menu close now by clicking. But when i click on the menu from the dropdown they also close - thats not correct. Can anybody help me?

```
            $('.nav a').on('click', function () {
            if ($(".navbar-toggle").is(":visible"))
            {
                $(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
            }
        });
```

Menu:

- Menu title 1
- Menu title 2 (dropdown) -> Item 1, Item2, Item 3

When i click now in Menu title2 they also close...

Comment: provide some html or jsfiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the selector for which you attach on event to:

```
$('.nav li:not(.dropdown) a')
```

See updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sack847t/3/).